# Amazon - error while validating the input provided for the PutObject operation

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm getting this error when i'm trying to upload file on amazon server

*"Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the PutObject operation:
[Body] must be an fopen resource, a GuzzleHttp\Stream\StreamInterface object, or something that can be cast to a string. Found array(5)"*

I found here similar issue https://github.com/CodeSleeve/stapler/issues/145
it can be solved by downgrade sdk to 2.0 but I would like to stick to my 3.11, any ideas ?